# How do I make an auto-scrolling dynamic txt field with actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip

I'm trying to add scrolling text to a small mp3 player application I'm working on and I'm running across some problems. Namely, that I'm not that well versed in movie clips.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any good actionscipt 3 tutorials for auto-scrolling text or basic movie clips stuff (frames etc.). I've found lots of tutorials but the all seem just a bit out of my reach. Thanks for your attention, Dan

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution to making something scroll in my opinion.

layer 1 (Mask layer -> make a mask for the scrollable area
layer 2 (Masked layer)-> put your displayobject (textfield/movieclip/..) there

control the scrolling by adjusting the y axis of the masked layer

it's fast and definitely not that hard to do